# Why isn't this flip sprite function working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So basically I made this flip function that flips the sprite around and it usually works, but for the game I am currently working on it wont flip it around when it is called. Here is the function.

```
void Flip()
{
    print("flip");
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
    Scaler.x *= -1f;
    transform.localScale = Scaler;
}
```

And I know that it is using the function when I want it too because it is printing the "flip" in the debug log. Anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Why not simply use [`SpriteRenderer.flipX`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html) ?

Comment: I want to use scale instead because in my game sometimes the object being flipped has childrenObjects that I want to be flipped in relation.

Comment: Have attached this script to the object to be flip? What do you mean by not working, whether unexpected results or just not result?

Comment: As in it doesn't work. It prints flip when I want it to flip but it doesn't actually flip it.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Vector3 Scaler = transform.localScale;
   Scaler *= Vector3.left;
```

Comment: While your code may be correct, can you please give some explanation as to why?

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure why you're having this issue. I suspect it is in your logic determining when to call the flip function. However, you said you are getting the print at the correct time? The code below works for changing the way the sprite faces.

```
transform.localscale = new Vector2(-1, 0);
transform.localscale = new Vector2(1, 0);
```